# How to get CDMA Pilot PN of android phone?

Tags: android, cdma

Can we get CDMA Pilot PN number of android phone? 
PN code is Pseudo-random Noise code of CDMA phone, it's very important parameter of CDMA system, but after several weeks search, I can not find the way to get it. 
Can someone help me out? 
May be get it from RIL? But how?

Answer (score 2):

The `Motorola 4G RAZR Max` will go into test mode by dialing `##387`.

You will get a request for `SPC Passcode`, enter `000000` and tap on `Verify`.

The first screen and the first item displayed will be the `PN offset of the strongest active pilot`.

Hope this is helpful.